# How to use same component while maintaining different Mobx store?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, mobx, mobx-react

I have a component called keypair.js

1. On clicking add button, it creates three text boxes and one delete button.
2. on clicking delete button, it deletes that row.

This is like postman implementation, so this keypair will be used as Header component as well as Parameter component.

Now, when I am using this as a reusable component, whatever changes I am making at Header component it is also reflected at Parameter component.

I have tried to export the store class as well and creating instance on the individual component but that also doesn't work. Check my previous implementation below which work but state is shared between the two components.

Comment: Nobody is going, or want to understand your code, plus it seems unnecessary.

Comment: Man's pasting an essay, you should build an example with the least code possible to represent your problem

Comment: Thanks for the comments - @BARNOWL I wanted to make sure you people understand the problem statement, code is irrelevant but if any one likes to see its their choice. I wanted to know theoretical approach about it. No need to update my code.

Comment: Removing the code, as per the suggestion of fellow developers.

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer for it now. For maintaining different instances of store simply export 2 or more instances from the store itself. I don't know why exporting the store class and creating instance in the component doesn't work.